# Doing raster export from PostGIS to TIFF file

Tags: postgis, raster, export

I am trying to do a `lo_export` of a raster record in PostGIS table:

```
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';

SELECT oid, lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), tiff) As num_bytes
FROM
( VALUES (lo_create(0),
ST_Astiff( (SELECT rast FROM raster_table) )
) ) As v(oid,tiff);
```

Finally I did `SELECT lo_export(oid,'filesystempath');`

But when I check the file system path there is nothing there... Anybody know why?

And how can I do to generate the TIFF file?

Answer (score 1):

the function `lo_export()` you use is a [*server* side function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-funcs.html).

Maybe your file was written into a system directory such as `/usr/.../postgresql/...` on the server-side (which may be a remote machine) or had issues with access privileges.

I think you can use `\lo_export` in the [`psql` client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) if you intend to generate the output image in the file system of your *client* machine:

> \lo_export loid filename
>
> Reads the large object with OID loid from the database and writes it to filename. Note that this is subtly different from the server
>   function lo_export, which acts with the permissions of the user that
>   the database server runs as and on the server's file system.